# Trying to loop to create several objects, then assign three textbox values from winform to each object

Tags: vb.net, winforms, oop

I have a Remote control for several Over IP IR blasters. I want to be able to configure each IR blaster details (Name of channel, IP address, and the IR port) I was able to do it using visual studio settings, but as it saves to appdata in a unique folder, It isn't viable.

So I am recreating it with trying to save to XML, but I have 20 different channels to add so I was trying to do something like this

Class:

```
Public Class channel
     Public Ip As String
     Public Name As String
     Public Hostport As String
End Class
```

Code:

```
Dim I As Integer 
Do While I <= 20
     Dim channel[I] As New channel
     channel[I].Name = Channel_[I]_Textbox.Text
     channel[I].Ip[I].Text
     channel[I].Hostport = irsel[I].SelectedIndex
Loop
```

But as I'm newer to coding, I'm not sure if I'm even taking the right approach
or if it is even possible to declare like this. (I know this code doesn't work)

I have a functional program, just trying to make it save correctly.

Comment: There's a few things in there that aren't right. Try to initialize about 5 channels for start without the loop, hard coding each number and putting them in a list. Then, when that work, use a loop. I would even start by just initializing the name of 5 channel first. Then do the IP, ect...

Comment: And how should I code the loop, that is the main issue. I can't figure out how to correctly code above. I know how to hard code, but that would end up with a lot of lines of code.

Comment: Some of those line don't make sense and would be hard for us to know what is the correct way. Why don't you put an example that initialize 3 hard coded channel that actually works, then we can easily help you put this in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you've got a series of controls on your form that you want to retrieve values from?  You might have "Channel_1_Textbox", "Channel_2_Textbox", etc., and "irsel1", "irsel2", etc...

If so, use [Controls.Find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.7.2), as in the example below.  The code also demonstrates how to create an instance of your class, populate it, then add it to a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
Private channels As New List(Of channel)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 1 To 20
        Dim ctlName As Control = Me.Controls.Find("Channel_" & i & "_Textbox", True).FirstOrDefault
        Dim ctlHostport As Control = Me.Controls.Find("irsel" & i, True).FirstOrDefault
        If Not IsNothing(ctlName) AndAlso Not IsNothing(ctlHostport) Then
            Dim tbName As TextBox = DirectCast(ctlName, TextBox)
            Dim cbHostport As ComboBox = DirectCast(ctlHostport, ComboBox) ' <-- not sure what kind of control you're using!

            Dim ch As New channel
            ch.Name = tbName.Text
            ' ch.Ip = ??? unclear if you're retrieving from a control, or a different array?
            ch.Hostport = cbHostport.SelectedItem.ToString
            channels.Add(ch)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So when it creates a new channel then adds it to array, How do you reference it?

Comment: It's a **List**, not an Array, but you can access it in the same way by using an Index, such as: `channels(indexNumber).Name = "Bob"`

Comment: This works for me, for the most part, now I just need to figure out how to export and import from XML correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list or array of channels, you must create it first, outside the loop. Then you add each channel to your list inside the loop:

```
Dim channels = New List(Of Channel)()
Dim i As Integer 'Local variables are usually lowercase in VB.NET
Do While i < 20 'Integer is 0-based, so loop from 0 to 19
     Dim channel = New Channel()

     'channel.Name = ...
     'channel.Ip = ...
     'channel.Hostport = ...

     channels.Add(channel)
Loop
```